# iis7 url rewrite friendly url

Tags: iis-7, web-config, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to do an url rewrite for dynamic pages in the admin section of my website, but nothing is changes when I upload the web.congif file.

Also, I would like for the web.config file to be in the admin directory and not in the root.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

current address looks like www.site.com/admin/mypage.php?id=5&name=$name

Would like it to look like www.site.com/admin/mypage/5/Jack

Below is the code that I'm using, but nothing changes? Please help?!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite to mypage.php" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^mypage/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="mypage.php?id={R:1}&amp;name={R:2}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```